# SharePoint 2010 site image as footer

Tags: css, site, footer

I am trying to add image as footer to the SharePoint site which should be applicable to all of the pages. I tried to do this through masterpage modification adding an extra div after the end of s4-workspace class. Added some css to apply my image to footer but the image is getting bigger and showing all over the bottom of the page, I have modified my s4-bodycontainer to have fixed look of my site. 
I am using below code to set this up

```
fixed-footer {
position: fixed;
padding:20px;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #000;
background-image:url('Improve.png') !important;
```

and the s4-container I modified is below

```
#s4-bodyContainer, #top-curve{
width: 944px !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
clear: both;}
```

can someone help me on how to get the fixed footer using an image as footer to my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for footer issue. Added an extra div before  **SharePoint:DeveloperDashboard** in master page. This will create footer image applied to the pages. This also creates footer to modal pop up in the site where this master page applies. If you don't want to show the footer in modal pop up windows just add **s4-notdlg** in the div which you create for footer as shown below code.

```
<div class="main-content">
                    <a name="mainContent"></a>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="s4-notdlg"><img src="/Style%20Library/Images/File.png" style="width:963px;" alt=""></img></div>
            <!--End of Footer Code-->
            <div id="DeveloperDashboard" class="ms-developerdashboard">
                <SharePoint:DeveloperDashboard runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <div id="fixed-footer"></div>
        </div>
```

this has resolved my issue.Hope this might be useful to the needy people in future.